# problems generating 32 bit random numbers

Tags: c++, random, 32-bit

I want to generate a random number between specified range, but when i run the following code. it gives error , can any one explain the error please?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
using namespace std;
unsigned long int starting=2347483648;
unsigned long int ending=3994967296;
unsigned int rand(unsigned long int first,unsigned long int last)
{
    std::random_device rd; 
    std::mt19937 eng(rd()); 
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> distr(first, last); 
    return  (unsigned int)distr(eng) << ' '; 
}
int main()
{
  cout<<rand(1,ending);//generate random number in this range
}
```

The program breaks and gives an error

> invalid min and max arguments for uniform_int

Explain the reason of error and tell me how can i generate the random numbers between the above specified range

Comment: If I'm not wrong, the default template argument for `uniform_int_distribution` is an int. And an unsigned long int cannot fit into an int.

Comment: well if the above function is called with these values rand(starting,ending), it works fine...

Comment: I gotta say, the tone of the question is not so nice..

Comment: i didn't understand @fleetC0m ...... i didn't mean anything like that...just here for learning

Comment: I don't see why the downvotes. This problem could trip anybody up if they weren't familiar with `uniform_int_distribution`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
    std::uniform_int_distribution<unsigned long int> distr(first, last); 
    return  (unsigned int)distr(eng); 
}
```

I also removed the errorneous `<< ' '` which is left-shifting with an space character, rather than appending a space to the output.

```
int main()
{
  cout<<rand(1,ending) << " ";
}
```

When `ending` (or last) is converted into an int, it becomes `-300000000`. `ending` also becomes `max()` for distr, so `ending` == `distr.max()`. Using `std::numeric_limits<int>::min()`, we can see that the resulting value can fit into an int.

Comment: Yes it works but can you explain why the above code gives error if first argument is 1 and runs if it is "starting"